# Add leading zeroes only if it begin with digit in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame column which have special characters and numbers. I want to have leading zeroes only if it begin with a digit. I need  a total of 3 digits.
I tried the following code:

```py
df['input'] = df['input'].str.zfill(3)
```

## Input:

| column |
| --- |
| 1 |
| $500 |
| 333 |
| 2 |
| (8 |
| ?8 |
| 5 |
| 1 |
| 444 |

## Output:

| column |
| --- |
| 001 |
| $500 |
| 333 |
| 002 |
| (8 |
| ?8 |
| 005 |
| 001 |
| 444 |

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are trying to accomplish. I suggest posting a more clear representation of what your input and output are.

Comment: Please add more examples

Comment: My dataframe column contains the above input and output. I wanted to  have leading 0's if the value begin with  a digit and if it begin with special character it can ignore adding 0's. I need a total of 3 digit including 0's.

Comment: Just use a `zfill(3)` with a mask. The mask can be calculated with a `isdigit()`. check my answer for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get what you want by:

```
df_merge['output'] = df_merge['input'].apply(lambda x : f'{x:0>3}' if x[0] in '0123456789' else x)
```

**Verification**

Assume the followin example to simulate the case you gave:

```
import pandas as pd
df_merge = pd.DataFrame({'input':['1','$500','333','2','(8','?8']})
```

print(df_merge['input'])

```
0       1
1    $500
2     333
3       2
4      (8
5      ?8
Name: input, dtype: object
```

now apply:

```
df_merge['output'] = df_merge['input'].apply(lambda x : f'{x:0>3}' if x[0] in '0123456789' else x)
```

print(df_merge['output'])

```
0     001
1    $500
2     333
3     002
4      (8
5      ?8
Name: output, dtype: object
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  What this is doing f'{x:0>3}'. ?

Comment: **First:** your thanks should come with `accepting my answer ` and `voting up` - **Second:** Regarding ` f'{x:0>3}'`, `x` is a reference to the input value, `0` is the charcter to fill, and `>3` means complete the input with '0's upto 3 characters.

Comment: Can you answer the below question :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605150/missing-columns-in-final-html-table-after-rendering-the-pandas-dataframe-to-html

Comment: Welcome, I will say, but have you accepted my answer here to go there? You have just voted without accepting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a elegant way using `zfill` along with a mask.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'strings':['1','$500','333','2','(8','?8','5','1','444']})

#Mask for checking if first alphabet is digit
mask = df.strings.str[0].str.isdigit()

#Apply zfill on values where mask is True
df.loc[mask, 'strings'] = df.strings.str.zfill(3)
print(df)
```

```
  strings
0     001
1    $500
2     333
3     002
4      (8
5      ?8
6     005
7     001
8     444
```

Comment: updated the dummy data for reproducability.

Comment: Thank you Akshay.

Comment: Can you pls help to resolve the issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605150/missing-columns-in-final-html-table-after-rendering-the-pandas-dataframe-to-html

Comment: @Karthikchengalvarayan, using apply is highly inefficient. let me know if the above approach is unclear because using `str` methods is significantly better and more readible.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['1','$500','333','2','(8','?8','5','1','444'], columns=['input'])

# Contains uses regex.
ix = df['input'].str.contains('^[0-9]')
df.loc[ix, 'input'] = df.loc[ix, 'input'].str.zfill(3)
df

>>>  input
0   001
1  $500
2   333
3   002
4    (8
5    ?8
6   005
7   001
8   444
```

Answer (score 0):

use map and function to zero pad numeric values

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'strings':['1','$500','333','2','(8','?8','5','1','444']})

def zero_pad(x):
    if x.isdigit():
        return x.zfill(3)
    else:
       return x

df['strings']=df['strings'].map(zero_pad)
print(df)
```

output
strings

```
0     001
1    $500
2     333
3     002
4      (8
5      ?8
6     005
7     001
8     444
```

​