# Missing columns in final html table after rendering the pandas dataframe to html

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2

I am writing the below df values into a html template. I am missing chemistry and algebra column in the final output html table.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Somu', 'Kiku', 'Amol', 'Lini'],
     'physics': [68, 74, 77, 78],
     'chemistry': [84, 56, 73, 69],
     'algebra': [78, 88, 82, 87]})
df_html = df.to_html()

    

  template_vars = { "html_table":df_html}

  f = open(output.html, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
  html_template ="metrics.html"
  temp = Template(open(html_template, 'r').read())
  template = temp.render(template_vars)
  f.write(template)
  f.close()
```

In the below Metrics.html has 4 buttons, out of which 2nd button is not showing up all the columns.

## Metrics.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
```

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

```
    <style>
        #incorrect-response-panel .panel{
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        .response-panel-title {
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .doc-info h3 {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    </style>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .collapsible {
      background-color: #777;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .active, .collapsible:hover {
      background-color: #555;
    }

    .collapsible:after {
      content: '\002B';
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .active:after {
      content: "\2212";
    }

    .content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
 <button id=button1 type="button" class="collapsible">Top 1 Correct answer </button>
    <div class="content">
        {{correct_tab1}}
    </div>
    <div>
        </br>  </br>
    </div>
    <button id=button2  type="button" class="collapsible">Top 1 Incorrect answer </button>
    <div class="content">
        {{html_table}}
    </div>

    <div>
        </br>  </br>
    </div>
    <button id=button3  type="button" class="collapsible">Top 1 Correct answer </button>
    <div class="content">
        {{correct_tab1}}
    </div>

    <div>
        </br>  </br>
    </div>
    <button id=button4  type="button" class="collapsible">Top 1 Incorrect answer </button>
    <div class="content">
        {{incorrect_tab1}}
    </div>
    
    <div>
        </br>  </br>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/code_rev/pen/VwKBpRY

Comment: What is the contents of `metrics.html`?

Comment: Its the template where it has the collapsible table with the sign +. If you click the button the output will get displayed there.                                                                          <button id=incorrect  type="button" class="collapsible"> Incorrect answer </button>
    <div class="content">
        {{html_table}}
    </div>

Comment: Also i have like 4 collapsible tables, only the 2nd table is not displaying all the columns. But the other 3 tables display the right columns.

Answer (score 0):

As I testing your code partly after romoving (`) in (`df=) and (`df_html=) in your qustion:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Somu', 'Kiku', 'Amol', 'Lini'],
     'physics': [68, 74, 77, 78],
     'chemistry': [84, 56, 73, 69],
     'algebra': [78, 88, 82, 87]})
df_html = df.to_html()
```

we find the content of df_html is (just reformating):

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">  
    <thead>    
    <tr style="text-align: right;">      
        <th></th>      
        <th>name</th>      
        <th>physics</th>      
        <th>chemistry</th>      
        <th>algebra</th>    
    </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody>    
    <tr>      
        <th>0</th>      
        <td>Somu</td>      
        <td>68</td>      
        <td>84</td>      
        <td>78</td>    
    </tr>    
    <tr>      
        <th>1</th>      
        <td>Kiku</td>      
        <td>74</td>      
        <td>56</td>      
        <td>88</td>    
    </tr>    
    <tr>      
        <th>2</th>      
        <td>Amol</td>      
        <td>77</td>      
        <td>73</td>      
        <td>82</td>    
    </tr>    
    <tr>      
        <th>3</th>      
        <td>Lini</td>      
        <td>78</td>      
        <td>69</td>      
        <td>87</td>    
    </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

so we find the complete DataFrame with all the columns.

Hence, this part of the code is correct (after removing the character (`) I mentioned above).

The only suspicious sentence, in my thought, is

```
 template = temp.render(template_vars)
```

which depneds on `html_template ="metrics.html"` and `template_vars = { "html_table":df_html}`

Therefore, if there is a problem still existed, it would be necessary to add 'metrics.html`. we may find something.

**Extending**
In the 'metrics.html` you uploaded, I have changed the following part:

```
    <button id=correct1 type="button" class="collapsible">Correct answer </button>
    <div class="content">
        {{correct_tab1}}
    </div>
    <div>
        </br>  </br>
    </div>
    <button id=incorrect1  type="button"
```

to

```
    <button id=correct1 type="button" class="collapsible">Correct answer </button>
    <div class="content">
        {{html_table}} <!-- to match your question -->
    </div>
    <div>
        </br>  </br>
    </div>
```

then after running your code, the rendered part in `output.html` related to the table we intend is:

```
    <button id=incorrect1  type="button" class="collapsible"> Incorrect answer </button>
    <div class="content">
        <table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>physics</th>
      <th>chemistry</th>
      <th>algebra</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>Somu</td>
      <td>68</td>
      <td>84</td>
      <td>78</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Kiku</td>
      <td>74</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>88</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Amol</td>
      <td>77</td>
      <td>73</td>
      <td>82</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Lini</td>
      <td>78</td>
      <td>69</td>
      <td>87</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>

    <div>
        </br>  </br>
    </div>
```

so we notice that `{{html_table}}` we replaced correctly with HTML code of the table including all the columns.

so I do not find any problem.

I guess, you may investigate an old version of `output.html` and the generated one is in another folder.

***or as it is clear, you did not upload the 'metrics.html` you work with, since the uploaded one does not contain the HTML you added in your question***

Comment: Sure, ' this is just the formatting error. I can attach the metrics.html, if you could let me know how i can attach it.

Comment: can you edit your question? if so, just add it to the end of your question.

Comment: I have edited the question by adding metrics.html. My template is big enough. But i copied the items which we need. There are 4 collapsible tab, out of which second table is not showing all columns. Look for button2 and html_table.

Comment: Put `metrics.html` in google drive, and share the link in your question.

Comment: I cant put my html in drive. Is there any other way we can resolve this ?

Comment: you also can put your code in (https://codepen.io/), then send the link. you should master handlling files via many ways.

Comment: https://codepen.io/code_rev/pen/VwKBpRY. I have added in the question also. Pls look the pencode.

Comment: I have added the metrics.html. Can you pls look ?

Comment: Welcome, but did read ***Extending*** in my answer after editing. now, when I check the file you uploaded in https://codepen.io/code_rev/pen/VwKBpRY , I do not find any relation to `{{html_table}}`. so, how do you expect rendering to be done?

Comment: Nour, the html which i uploaded is the exact one which am using. Here in stack overflow i have put it as a sample one. Hence there will be no relation with the variables. But my problem is the second button is not rendering the full table. But the code given here is the same code which i am using in my project.

Comment: As seen in **Extending** I have changed the HTML seen to make the table rendering work, and all the columns appeared, try, what I did, and waiting.

Comment: I see you changed the variable name. I understand that. But thats not my problem. My data is not getting populated in the html table.

Comment: I have run the HTML file after the changed I mentioned and I did face any of the problems you mentioned. Please, review the HTML file you use, and mark the differences between the changed I made and your file, and compare it with the published one on https://codepen.io/code_rev/pen/VwKBpRY - Your are welcome.

Comment: All you have changed is just the variable name, right ?Anything else you did ? I can see any.

Comment: yes,  I tried to help, but unfortunately, the whole picture is not clear. Good Luck

Comment: Lets do a different approach. How to have a scroll bar in the final output table aftre rendering  like vertical and horizontal. In a way we can get the missed columns by having scroll bars.

Comment: First, try to put codes and HTML that reproduce the problem you see. No one can see your column problems. No one even made a comment.

Comment: I will do that.